# Rotate Photo on browser

Tags: image, rotation

This might not be some thing related to any coding language but may be some one knows a fix!! 
 Problem is have uploaded a photo on drop-box under the public folder so that i can share it with any one. So i copied the 'drop-box public link' and want to share this http link. 
But when some one opens the link in his browser the photo is rotated 90degrees anti clock wise but the actual photo is standing straight in 90 degree. Any solution to make my photo viewable normally on browser.

Thanks a lot... 
Heres the link any ways,its an idol. 
 https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37811825/Photos/IMG_0172.JPG

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the photo with any picture editing software and upload it again. That would be the most simple solution.

Comment: need to search for free picture editing sofwares for mac then.. Thanks

Comment: You can do this with the Preview Application on Mac. Just press cmd+L or cmd+R for rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. This is an issue with the poto, your OS shows it according to the meta tags in the picture, while the browser shows it like it really is.

So you should rotate the photo on your PC and upload it again with the correct angle!

Comment: Oh ok, am using a mac currently, in windows i know how to rotate it but if you know any method to rotate on the mac would be helpfull.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

on a MAC

Create a new folder on your Desktop.
Right click (Control click) to Attach Folder Action.
You'll get the Folder Actions Scripts.
Go down to the Image-Rotate (left or right) and attach.

Then just drop the images in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem with Dropbox, possibly for different reason. Uploaded a photo I had saved in landscape orientation but Dropbox was automatically rotating it 90°. Finally realized the photo originally was taken in portrait orientation and I had rotated it to landscape per my own viewing preference, however when I re-saved, I included the original photo EXIF data from the camera indicating it was in portrait mode, so I believe Dropbox was rotating the image based on the EXIF data. Saved it again without the EXIF data and Dropbox displays it as I intend.